# Evaluating and plotting $Sum[If[ m^2 + n^2 != 0, 1./(m^2 + n^2) ], {m, -1000, 1000}, {n, -1000, 1000}]$ for different ranges?

Tags: plotting, summation, series-expansion

I have a sum in Mathematica as follows:

```
Sum[If[ m^2 + n^2 != 0, 
 1./(m^2 + n^2) ], {m, -1000, 1000}, {n, -1000, 1000}]
```

and I have to manually change the intervals for $m = n = [-t, t]$ in order to see how the value of the sum changes. This is very inefficient!

What I would like to do is evaluate this sum for a range of $t$'s and plot the results as a graph against $t$. Say if $t$ starts at $t = 2$, the sum gets evaluated, then $t$ gets doubled, the sum gets evaluated again,...and so on,.., and then finally plotting the results. How can I do this in Mathematica? I can do it simply in Matlab with a for loop but I'm trying to learn Mathematica as it seems it could be better for certain computations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this not what you want ?

Define a function of t

```
sum[t_] := Sum[
  If[m^2 + n^2 != 0, 1./(m^2 + n^2), 1], {m, -t, t}, {n, -t, t}]
```

Create a Table of sums for a range of t values.

```
sums = Table[{t, sum[t]}, {t, 2, 100, 2}]
```

Plot the data

```
ListPlot[sums]
```

[image]

Note: Your If statement was incomplete. I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:

```
f[t_] := Total[1/((#.# & /@ Tuples[Range[-t, t], 2]) /. {0 -> 1})]
DiscretePlot[f[t], {t, 2, 100}]
```

[image]